# check the source of a file

Tags: php

i want php code to open a file and search in it for some dangerous words like

```
if(preg_match("/(echo|zend|print|print_r|phpinfo|
symlink|ini_set|telnet|cgi|
eval|base64_encode|base64_decode)/iU",$filesource)){
echo 'error';
}
```

how i can make it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse PHP code, use [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to get an array of [language tokens](http://php.net/tokens).

Answer (score 0):

pretty much like you outlined :)

But have you looked at tools like phpcs and phpcpd?

You can open up any php file like a regular text file and parse through it without including it in your script.

```
<?php
$filedata = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.php');
if (preg_match('/foo/', $filedata) {
    echo "file contained 'foo'\n";
}
```

Comment: if i want bar too'/foo/','/bar/' ? howi can make it